# Elementor left widget panel show loading forever

Tags: wordpress, elementor

suddenly, my local Elementor keep showing loading forever. I checked for any php error but there is none. Any could say why this happen?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of common reason of this issue is lack of memory. Try to add this code:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

in the **wp-config.php** file - above the line:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution regarding this and it is based on deactivating woocommerce to update any page with elementor, after successfully saving changes, we proceed to activate woocommerce and the problem is fixed.